# Importing data in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

So I am learning to use networkx now and my first step is to import a network data with the following code:

```
G_fb = nx.read_edgelist("~/Downloads/data.csv", create_using = nx.Graph(), nodetype = int)
```

An error prompted saying that FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Downloads/data.csv'

However, if I use the code below, there is no error, and the file is successfully located:

```
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/data.csv")
```

I have checked the documentation for read_edgelist and do not find any special requirement on the path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the two filenames are different.  `'bridge.csv' != 'data.csv'`

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to change that. They are both the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Pandas, NetworkX does not do user expansion. The character "~" is treated literally as a part of the path. You have to do the user expansion yourself:

```
from os.path import expanduser
nx.read_edgelist(expanduser("~/Downloads/data.csv"), ...)
```